# How would I assign a value to a datetime field in an Access table in VBA?

Tags: vba, datetime, ms-access

I have an Access table with a DateTime field. From what I have tried thus far, you cannot assign a VBA Date variable to an Access Table Datetime field.

When I assign the return value of a `CDATE()` function, the DateTime field in the Access table is an empty date.

```
    readingSet.AddNew                              
    
    readingSet!jobinstrumentimportid = jobInstImportId
    readingSet!ReadingDate = CDate("10/13/2021 4:05:05 PM")
    readingSet!readingTime = lineArray(1)
    readingSet!decibelreading = CDbl(lineArray(2))
    
    readingSet.Update
```

- If I check the `Day(CDate("10/13/2021 4:05:05 PM"))`, I get 13.
- If I check the `Hour(CDate("10/13/2021 4:05:05 PM"))`, I get 16.
- When I check the `Day(readingSet!ReadingDate)`, I get 0.
- When I check the `Hour(readingSet!ReadingDate)`, I get 0.

If I assign the `CStr(CDate("10/13/2021 4:05:05 PM"))`:

- `reading!ReadingDate` is `6/29/2021`.

If I assign `DateValue(CDate("10/13/2021 4:05:05 PM")) + TimeSerial(16, 5, 5)` to readingSet!ReadingDate:

- `reading!ReadingDate` is `6/29/2021`.

Is there a way to assign a VBA Date field to an Access table DateTime field?

Comment: What you describe is not possible, so either this is not the full story, or something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I would double check, and open that table in design mode, and double, triple, quadruple check the data type for that column.

this works fine for me:

```
Dim rst        As DAO.Recordset

Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblhotels")

rst.Edit
rst!MyDate = CDate("10/13/2021 4:05:05 PM")

Debug.Print rst!MyDate
Debug.Print Hour(rst!MyDate)
Debug.Print Day(rst!MyDate)


rst.Update
```

OutPut:

```
2021-10-13 4:05:05 PM 
16 
13
```

So you are missing some big detail here, as what you have looks fine.

Perhaps this is a linked table to some external data source? But then again, that would a really spectacular detail of epic proportions to leave out.

So, I would check the table in design mode, and see what kind of data type that column is being see/view/known as by access.

From the code you posted, that format and column looks just fine.

You could of course consider this as a test, but it not really required.

```
rst!MyDate = DateSerial(2021, 10, 13) + TimeSerial(16, 5, 5)

Debug.Print rst!MyDate
Debug.Print Hour(rst!MyDate)
Debug.Print Day(rst!MyDate)
```

So, the other possible is that your regional settings on your computer are messed up.

As a general rule, you want to set the control on the form as formatted to date or date time.

Then, you can in most cases just assign the control to the column in the reocrdset.

But, so far, you need to check the date time and setting for that column in the table.

However, as a general rule, if you going to specify a string for a date, then follow the ISO format like this:

```
 rst!MyDate = CDate("2021-10-13 4:05:05 PM")
```

This will work and be "far more" immune to regional settings.

since the question then becomes is 13 the date, or is 13 the month that can't exist (1-12 only allowed)?